# In Access, how can I create a method to create about 152 different files from one table?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a table that has about 1500 students and their teacher. There are 152 teachers. The collective students a teacher has is their caseload. I want to output an Excel file that will show their caseload. If I was doing this brute force, it would be an easy matter. However, is there a way that I can set it up so that Access can loop through and make an excel file for EACH teacher. In addition to my student table, I have a teacher table that has all of the teachers. I also assigned each of them a number so that a loop could count through them. I understand the structure of what I want to do, I just don't know the best way to go about it.. or the code honestly, haha.  Either way, what I have below is what is in the tables, basically. The table names are Students and Teachers.

```
Students
 Student_Number Student_Name   Teacher_Number

Teachers
 Teacher_Number   Teacher_Name
```

That is basically what I have here. I do realize that for normal situations, It is a horrible decision to use a name as a connecting field. However, this isn't going to be any bigger than these two fields and I will have to do this from scratch each year so I don't forsee there being any issues with duplicate names since we don't have any for this year. Basically, these tables won't be changing so I don't have to worry about updating. Basically, for this small thing, I am not worrying about normalizing etc.

Comment: It is not about database design, it is an example of outputting data to Excel using two tables. Think of the student table as a query against the junction table, if it makes it easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the teacher table and assign a string to an existing query.

```
 Dim qdf As QueryDef
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

 ''Make sure you have a query that can be overwritten called OutputStudents
 ''or this will not work. You can create a query in VBA and do the checks 
 ''as to whether a query by that name exists, but this is simpler
 Set qdf = CurrentDB.Querydefs("OutputStudents")
 Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("Teachers")

 Do While Not rs.EOF
    ''Set the sql of a query called OutputStudents (see above)
    qdf.SQL = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Teacher_Number=" & rs!Teacher_Number

    ''Output to Excel
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, _
       qdf.Name, "Z:\docs\" _
       & Teacher_Number & ".xls", True
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Or there abouts.